# SimpleHTMLDOM - Get iframe src link

Tags: php, iframe, simple-html-dom

How to get the "thesrc" link from the iframe tag with SimpleHTMLDOM?

The source of the page i want the data from:

```
<div class="ui-tab-pane" data-role="panel" id="feedback">
 <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" 
width="100%" height="200" 
thesrc="//feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.html?productId=32795263337&ownerMemberId=228319068&companyId=237873399&memberType=seller&startValidDate=&i18n=true"></iframe>
</div>
```

So i tried:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Global-Version-Xiaomi-Redmi-Note-4-Mobile-Phone-3GB-RAM-32GB-ROM-Snapdragon-625-Octa-Core/32795263337.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//div[#class='ui-tab-pane']") as $node){
echo $node->getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]->getAttribute("thesrc");
echo $node->getElementsByTagName('div')[0]->nodeValue;
}

?>
```

It returns nothing. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the XPath stuff to achieve this. Have a look here:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$iFrame = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe')->item(0);
$src = $iFrame->getAttribute('thesrc');

echo $src;
```

Which gives you:

```
//feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.html?productId=32795263337&ownerMemberId=228319068&companyId=237873399&memberType=seller&startValidDate=&i18n=true
```

See it working here https://3v4l.org/41CRj

Comment: Great solution and it's working flawless! Thank you :)

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help

Comment: @Jack This will get all `iframe` with in the `DOM`. If this is what you want then this is the perfect solution.

Comment: @sahil, `item(0)` returns the first iframe. He can change zero to whichever he needs. You can also get elements by id, if they have one.

Comment: @delboy1978uk Your solution is perfectly okay, but i was expecting that OP is kinda querying over DOM for some `iframe` which is inside a `div`. Like in its post he querying with this `//div[#class='ui-tab-pane']`, But in your post  just saying `getElementsByTagName` will return all iframes which are outputside of a div.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. 
Instead of querying`//div[#class='ui-tab-pane']` over `div` and then finding `iframe`, 
You can query iframe directly with `//div[@class="ui-tab-pane"]/iframe`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/869110)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$string=<<<STR

<div class="ui-tab-pane" data-role="panel" id="feedback">
    <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" height="200" thesrc="//feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.html?productId=32795263337&ownerMemberId=228319068&companyId=237873399&memberType=seller&startValidDate=&i18n=true"></iframe>
</div>

STR;

$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($string);

$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$results = $domXPath->query('//div[@class="ui-tab-pane"]/iframe');
print_r($results->item(0)->getAttribute("thesrc"));
```

**Output:**

```
//feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.html?productId=32795263337&ownerMemberId=228319068&companyId=237873399&memberType=seller&startValidDate=&i18n=true
```